# PostgreSQL connection WITH OpenS(QL)hift from a Local OS X Python Script

Tags: postgresql, openshift, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to OpenShift from a OS X Python Script.  OpenShift for sure works.  However, I'm looking for an "easy" way with python without downloading additional PGSQL libs to OS X.  Thanks!

Question: What is the correct domain name to use for this??  And can we keep it simple without doing an import to python?

I don't want to use any additional libraries.

the main problem I'm having is with pgsql.connect(dbname = 'orion', host = '127.7.74.2:5432', #'localhost', port = 5432, user = 'earthling', password = 'extraterrestrial')

Here is what the code file looks like "pgsql.py"...

```
# PostgreSQL Client:
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html

# PostgreSQL Server:
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime.html

# PostgreSQL Commands:
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference.html

# PostgreSQL Data Types:
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'orion',
                host = '127.7.74.2:5432', #'localhost',
                port = 5432,
                user = 'earthling',
                password = 'extraterrestrial')

sql = conn.cursor()

def CREATE_TABLE(table, text):
    sql.execute("CREATE TABLE " + table + " (" + text + ");")

def INSERT(table, url, text):
    #date = datetime.date.today()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print date
    query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (url, text, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
    params = (url, text, date,)
    sql.execute(query, params)

def SELECT(table, url):
    query = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE url = %s;"
    sql.execute(query, (url,))

def QUERY(text):
    sql.execute(text)

INSERT("main", "www.whoi.edu", "test")
print SELECT("main", "www.whoi.edu")
```

[image: OpenShift User Menu]

Thanks for your help!

Question: This should fairly simple and shouldn't require psycopg2?

Comment: I talked with a friend and they basically said I have to use BREW or PIP to install a custom SQL access library.  When is python going to get a pgsql or mysql direct access???!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to use a local table (mini-hashtable) and this will be faster then connecting to a remote database.

However, the other *SOLUTION* is (i believe maybe possible with OpenShift) to create ROUTE an External path from OpenShift.  Here is what it MAYBE looks like if OpenShift supports this in the future.  Security can maybe work similar to dropbox style connections to a PostgreSQL server.  Hopefully these settings will help someone?  However, it maybe will not work unless some other admin settings are made??!  However, However, something maybe could work in the future? #local-made-up-mini-table-sql

[image: ROUTES External Traffic]

[image: CREATE ROUTE]

Comment: You cannot use a Route for a non HTTP protocol, with the exception of where the application is able to terminate a secure connection, you enable passthrough secure connection, and the client supports SNI over a TLS connection. PostgreSQL doesn't satisfy those requirements, so you can't use it even in that special case.

Comment: The only way in OpenShift Online to expose a non HTTP service such as PostgreSQL, is to use port forwarding to temporarily expose it to you local computer. There is no way of setting up such a service in a way that it is permanently exposed as OpenShift Online doesn't allow it, as doing so requires full cluster admin to set up and you don't have that.

Comment: Thanks!  I can maybe create my own mini-"postsql-table" csv file that works for what I need in terms of SQL and share or pass that around locally until I have something serious.  Its maybe the way its done by extremely large databases and beginners just like me? #hashtables

Answer (score 1):

Separate to the issue of client side libraries you need use port forwarding to expose the PostgreSQL database inside of OpenShift to your local computer. The IP address of the PostgreSQL service inside of OpenShift is not going to be externally visible. See the tutorial about port forwarding with OpenShift at:

- https://learn.openshift.com/

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what problem you're having when you attempt to connect?

As far as working with Python, we've had to use cx_oracle to connect to our oracle tables, so I'd expect you'd have to use psycopg2 to connect with PostGresQL as there's probably not a native functionality without a library.

However I just read you're on OS X, so it may be entirely different. Tag your question with OS X, see if that helps fetch an answer better.

Comment: I'm not sure what address I should use and also if there is a way to connect without downloading an additional library and just use default Python commands.  OPENSHIFT works... Its a problem on my end most likely.   I haven't been able to establish a connection because of a missing library?  :(

Comment: You've probably tried this, but are you able to connect to the server via PuTTy or a similar platform? That at least would settle whether you're using the correct address.

Comment: Okay, let me try port 8080 on this.  Thanks!  However, I don't have a server other then SQL on there.